# JavaFX: Why css properties start with -fx?

Tags: css, javafx

I am reading about `JavaFX` and its ability to do CSS, but I see that a lot of properties start with `-fx`, i.e. `JavaFX` specific.

E.g.:

```
-fx-font-family <font-family>   inherit  
-fx-font-size   <font-size> inherit  
-fx-font-style  <font-style>    inherit  
-fx-font-weight <font-weight>   inherit
```

Is there any particular reason for that? Why not use already standardized properties?

Comment: it's because the `-fx` prefix is for specific javafx features, read this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)

Comment: font-family fontsize and  style are hardly javafx specific.

Comment: -fx-font-family only allows you to add one font so I would say that is  a javafx specific feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `CSS Property` in javafx starts with `-fx`. This is just to show that these are specific to javafx !

From the documentation :

> The JavaFX CSS support and extensions have been designed to allow
>   JavaFX CSS style sheets to be parsed cleanly by any compliant CSS
>   parser, even though it might not support JavaFX extensions. This
>   enables the mixing of CSS styles for JavaFX and for other purposes
>   (such as for HTML pages) into a single style sheet. To this end, all
>   JavaFX property names have been prefixed with a vendor extension of
>   "-fx-". Even properties that might seem to be compatible with standard
>   HTML CSS have been prefixed, because JavaFX has somewhat different
>   semantics for their values.

which means that **though** (again from docs)

> JavaFX Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is based on the W3C CSS version
>   2.1 [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) with some additions from current work on version 3 [2].

It still has some features specific to itself

> JavaFX CSS also has some extensions to CSS in support of specific JavaFX
>   features.

For the Complete reference please read the **Introduction** part from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html)